# In lWUIT, How to call main MIDlet class by click on back command?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

My question is how to call main `MIDlet` class by clicking on back `command`?
Suppose `MainMIDlet.java` this class extends `Form` and implements `ActionListener` and     `Aboutus.java` this class extends also include `Form` with implements `ActionListener`. In this class I had not created object of form. So in this class how to call `MainMIDlet` class when click on `Commmand` back button?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the MainMIDlet form instance when you call the Aboutus.java. 
For example,

**MainMIDlet.java**

```
 public class MainMIDlet extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {
    Form form = new form();
    ...
    ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            Command cmd = ae.getCommand();
            String cmdname= cmd.getCommandName();

            if (cmdname.equals("Aboutus"))
            {
                 Aboutus aboutus = new Aboutus(form); // pass the current form
                 aboutus.show();
            }
        }
}
```

**Aboutus.java**

```
public class Aboutus extends Form implements ActionListener {

Form mainform;

 public Aboutus(Form form) {
   this.mainform = form;
   ...
   ...
   Command backCommand = new Command("Back",null,1);
   this.setBackCommand(backCommand);
 }
    ...
    ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            Command cmd = ae.getCommand();
            String cmdname= cmd.getCommandName();

            if (cmdname.equals("Back"))
            {
                 mainform.showBack(); // show the Main Midlet form here
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bhakki yaar.You proovide best solution,but problem is when click on back command there is no action performed,i.e.MainMIDlet form can't be display.In my MainMIDlet class,all componet are add with the help of form object of MainMIDlet [Form form = new Form()]. what is problem? plz give soltion.THANK U

Comment: @Jeevan: Did you add the `addCommandListener` to second form?

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH bhakki.I forgot about this method. thanks dude once again.Take care.